# sfdx force:data:tree:export not returning all fields

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I have two custom objects on my scratch org:

Role__c

> - fields...

Role_Permission_c

> - Role__c (Lookup(Role))
> - Name (Text(80))
> - fields...

I would like to get all records from both objects. So I executed:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "SELECT Role__c, Name FROM Roles_Permission__c"
```

But I only get the field 'Name' in return

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Roles_Permission__c",
            "referenceId": "Roles_Permission__cRef1"
        },
        "Name": "delete_products"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Roles_Permission__c",
            "referenceId": "Roles_Permission__cRef2"
        },
        "Name": "read_products"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "Roles_Permission__c",
            "referenceId": "Roles_Permission__cRef3"
        },
        "Name": "add_products"
    }
  ]
}
```

I executed my SOQL Query on the workbench and also on the dev console. I got the field 'Role__c' as well.

I also tried this SOQL

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "SELECT (SELECT Name From Roles_Permission__r), Name FROM Roles_Permission__c"
```

But I got an error

> Didn't understand relationship 'roles_permission__r' in FROM part of
>   query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be
>   sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please
>   reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate name

How do I get Role__c from Role_Permission_c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outermost `SELECT` needs to be against your parent object, `Roles__c`:

```
SELECT (SELECT Name From Roles_Permission__r), Name FROM Roles__c
```

Then, your subquery may select the child objects, the `Roles_Permission__c` records. Note that the relationship name must be the one configured on the lookup field from the child to the parent, and it may not be the same as the sObject name with `__r` - it's often the plural name.